# How to connect Apple GPU to Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, applet, jupyter-lab

Currently, I am on Macbook pro M2 pro system. I want to set my jupyter notebook runtime on GPU cores rather than CPU cores. Since, I am working on ML Projects (using scikit-learn). ANy ides how to set the runtime to GPU clusters.